# Does ActiveDirectory support Kerberos user principle instances?

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

User principle instance has format `username/instance@REALM` and separate password. According to some [sources](https://sipb.mit.edu/doc/root-instance/) it's possible to create such principles in MIT Kerberos. Does ActiveDirectory support this Kerberos feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other Kerberos implementations may allow multiple UPN's for a given user, but MS AD does not. [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677605(v=vs.85).aspx#userPrincipalName)

> This attribute is an indexed string that is single-valued.